# I am getting the 'too many values to unpack' error on 3Dquiver. Any idea how I can fix this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just trying to compile this example, and I get the 'too many values to unpack' error

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)

plt.show()
```

Here's tell me that's the error that I get

```
in <module>()
     22 w=z*((y - b)/d_1 - (y - b)/d_2 + (y + b)/d_3 - (y + b)/d_4)
     23 
---> 24 ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)
     25 
     26 plt.show()
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? `x, y, z = np.meshgrid...`?

Comment: Edit your question and add your stack trace if you can.

Comment: It works for me as is

Answer (score 0):

You need at least version 1.4.x of matplotlib for 3D quiver plots.

I ran into this problem on Linux Mint 17.3 which only has 1.3.1.  The way I upgraded was to uninstall python-matplotlib, install python-pip, and install matplotlib (version 1.5.1) via:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```